ALB-Nginx_Ingress_Controller-Kubernetes_Pod&Service
I'm stuck a bit over here
I have deployed ingress-controller in my EKS cluster.
helm repo add ingress-nginx
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/
helm install ingress-controller ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace test-app --set controller.relicaCount=1 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector:"beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector:"beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme"="internet-facing" \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert"="arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:123456789:certificate/12233313-12312-13233-112-123311313" \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol"="http" \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports"="https"

The controller is working properly. I have deployed an ingress for it as well
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - prod.test.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: prod.test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-app-service
                port:
                  number: 80


The ingress is also up. I have created an app and service.
Now the issue is when I try to open the prod.test.com, it shows me 400 Bad Request, The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.
I'm not sure how to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried multiple blogs and post. I tried to recreate it but still the error is still the same
